# with area chart, how to get bottom values to show and be stretched all the way across graph

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts, area

http://jsfiddle.net/5b5mv/

^ this is what I have so far, I'm needing to get the graph to be stretched all he way across left to right, and I need the categories to show up underneath correctly.

Using the `xAxis { categories : ['values', 'value 2'] }` does not work when we make the graph going to the edges.

I found this example - http://jsfiddle.net/vKLPP/1/ that did achieve it, but the text underneath the columns needs to be an integer for that to work. Is there a way I can get it to work with a string as well?

Comment: So in your chart, how it should look like, can you attach any mockup ?

Comment: yeah sure - http://imgur.com/gmEtfMO

Comment: You should use categories in that way: http://jsfiddle.net/vKLPP/7/

Comment: Thats almost it, I cant have that white space on the left and right side. I'm trying to have the area/colored section go right up to the edge of the graph. Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/vKLPP/9/ but you'll see I commented the categories out to get it to stretch all the way across

Comment: Min/maxpadding works in all types except categoreis, but you can use workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/vKLPP/10/

Comment: Thanks! Thats one way, but I'm seeing I lost the values / hover effect on the first and last dot.

Comment: Reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3225